# Where does the formula to calculate a spatial filter diameter come from?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I understand that an image is the Fourier transform of the spatial profile of object. I know that a pinhole can therefore be used as a spatial filter to clear a gaussian beam from noise. I have read that the diameter of the pinhole to be used can be expressed as

$D_{pinhole} = \frac{8}{\pi}\frac{\lambda f}{D_{in}}$,

where $D_{in}$ is the diameter of the beam that gets filtered and $f$ is the focal length of the lens used to focus the beam on the pinhole. Where does this formula come from?

Comment: Looks like it's an adaptation of the Rayleigh criterion.

Comment: The optimum diameter of a pinhole corresponds to the smallest possible focal spot, given  the wavelength of the light, the diameter of the beam at the lens, and the focal length of the lens.  That is, indeed, just the inverse of the Rayleigh criterion.